# How to delete ContentDocument records associated with Agreements record

Tags: contentdocument

**As parentId in ContentDocument records is null, i am unable to locate and delete the records associated with Aggreements records. Is there any way to relate records between these two objects without parentId field.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ContentDocument` records are linked to their parents or share locations (of which there may be more than one) using [`ContentDocumentLink`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm#!) records. The `Id` of the parent record is stored in the `LinkedEntityId` field on `ContentDocumentLink`.

I suggest reading through the linked document as you try to design your queries, because there are some unusual restrictions on how you query `ContentDocumentLink`. In particular,

> A SOQL query must filter on one of Id, ContentDocumentId, or LinkedEntityId.

and

> You can't filter on the related object fields. For example, you can't filter on the properties of the account to which a file is linked. You can filter on the properties of the file, such as the title field.

Comment: Thanks David for your response. Will work on the solution provided by you and keep you posted.